# awk substitute shell variables

Tags: bash, variables, awk, substitution

I am struggling with awk substitution, for some reason the following code does not substitute anything, it just prints the output unaltered. Can anyone see what I am missing here? Any help would be very much appreachiated! (PS! The $DOCPATH and $SITEPATH are shell variables, they work perfectly fine in my awk setup).

```
awk -v docpath="$DOCPATH" -v sitepath="$SITEPATH" '{ sub( /docpath/, sitepath ) } { print }'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Saying:

```
sub( /docpath/, sitepath )
```

causes `awk` to replace the pattern `docpath`, not the variable `docpath`.

You need to say:

```
awk -v docpath="$DOCPATH" -v sitepath="$SITEPATH" '{sub(docpath, sitepath)}1' filename
```

Comment: this way is totally wrong way to go, should refer sed command which perreal provided.

Comment: Yeah, my actual script is bit more complex. I need to paste in suffix and prefix stuff as well. Awk therefor works well, but if my problem was isolated to this issue alone I would probably go for the sed solution. Thanks for your helpful feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't help to write this in sed:

```
sed 's/'"$DOCPATH"'/'"$SITEPATH"'/' input
```

Comment: since original awk command used sub(), you should not add g option in sed.

Comment: generally, if the variables (`$SITEPATH`) contain newlines this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`/docpath/` will search for the literal string  "docpath", not the variable as you want. Just use `sub(docpath, sitepath)`.

N.b. if there could be multiple matches in the same line, you'll want `gsub` instead of `sub`.